# How to make each header in a table clickable and add a chart to it?

Tags: 7, views, charts

I have used the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module to display an external database (which is working fine), but I want to make each header clickable and add a chart.

Is there a module to do this, or is there a way I can do this?

I found a few charting modules; some are good but they require me to create each chart manually, using the style and the data gets feed to it dynamically. The problem is that my tables have many headers; I flip the rows and columns but there are over 100 headers in it.

Answer (score 3):

There's no drag-and-drop solution. You would either have to create a custom module yourself that would do what you want, modify a module that gets close to what you want or use one of the solutions out there that makes you enter things in manually.